# Save multiple entries to same post in local storarge

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to save a shopping cart to local storage but having trouble to save it as I the way I want it to be saved. For each added order with the same id, the amount should increase and not create another duplicate of the input. I've got this semi-working with the first item/order but when I order more items they lay in the first order. And when I put the first order in again, it puts itself at the back and increases the amount in a weird way. Thankful for any help as I tried to fix this a couple of days now and tried a lot of different stuff with different results.

From local storage:
Button with id 88 pressed 4 times:

```
[{"id":"88","amount":4}]
```

Button with id 79 pressed 4 times:

```
[{"id":"88","amount":4},{"id":"79","amount":5}
,{"id":"79","amount":4},{"id":"79","amount":3},{"id":"79","amount":2}]
```

Then I press the button with id 88 again ONE time:

```
[{"id":"88","amount":5},{"id":"79","amount":5},{"id":"79","amount":4},
{"id":"79","amount":3},{"id":"79","amount":2},{"id":"88","amount":5},
{"id":"88","amount":5},{"id":"88","amount":5},{"id":"88","amount":5}]
```

And here is my javascript:

```
$("#btnBuyMovie").on("click", function () {

    var movieId = getParameterByName("productId");

    var amount = 1;

if (localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") !== null) {

        shoppingCartFromLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
        var newShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart(movieId, amount);

        for (var i = 0; i < shoppingCartFromLS.length; i++) {

            if (movieId != shoppingCartFromLS[i].id) {

           shoppingCartFromLS.push(newShoppingCart);
localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(shoppingCartFromLS));


            }
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < shoppingCartFromLS.length; i++) {

            if (movieId == shoppingCartFromLS[i].id) {

                shoppingCartFromLS[i].amount++;
            }
        }



        localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(shoppingCartFromLS));


    } if (localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") == null) {

        var shoppingCartFromLS = [];
        newShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart(movieId, amount);
        shoppingCartFromLS.push(newShoppingCart);
        localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(shoppingCartFromLS));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Following *for-loop* has multiple problems

- This line doesn't look correct.

Assuming you meant it to be this way, there is a semicolon at the end of it and it is pushing a *shopping cart* to the result of `push` function

```
if (movieId != shoppingCartFromLS[i].shoppingCartFromLS.push(newShoppingCart);
```

- Assuming the above line is what you meant it to be, you are checking if every item is not the same item you are looking for.

So, if that item is not found on any iteration, you add that item again.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < shoppingCartFromLS.length; i++) {
        if (movieId != shoppingCartFromLS[i].shoppingCartFromLS.push(newShoppingCart);
            localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(shoppingCartFromLS)); //this will happen for every item except the item that matches
        }
    }
```

Finally, this `for-loop` isn't required

```
   for (var i = 0; i < shoppingCartFromLS.length; i++) {
        if (movieId == shoppingCartFromLS[i].id) {
            shoppingCartFromLS[i].amount++;
        }
    }
```

**Solution**

You need to optimize your code this way

```
var isFound = shoppingCartFromLS.some( function( item ){
   var isFound = item.id == movieId; //this line is updated
   item.amount += isFound ? 1 : 0;
   return isFound;
})
if (!isFound)
{
  shoppingCartFromLS.push( { id : movieId, amount : 1 } )
}
localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(shoppingCartFromLS));
```

Comment: About the first for-loop: You're right, it was a typo/error when i edited my code in the editor on SO. It's updated now. Does this change your answer/solution?

Comment: @Halalbin ok, that is what I had thought too. In that case, check the analysis of your problem along with a solution.

Comment: I'm not getting it to work, maybe i missunderstood you. If i use your code the id stays the same regardless which id the movie have but the amount increases [{"id":"89","amount":27}]

Comment: @Halalbin My bad, just check the updates. Let me know the result.